# slice of errors to concrete types in Golang

Tags: go, error-handling

I'm playing around with error wrapping in Go and have a function that returns a wrapped custom error type. What I would like to do is iterate a list of expected errors and test if the output of the function wraps these the expected errors.

I've found that putting custom errors inside a `[]error` means that the type of the custom errors will be `*fmt.wrapError`, which means `errors.As()` pretty much always return true.

As an example, consider the following code:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type AnotherError struct {
}

func (e *AnotherError) Error() string {
    return "another error"
}

type MissingAttrError struct {
    missingAttr string
}

func (e *MissingAttrError) Error() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("missing attribute: %s", e.missingAttr)
}

func DoSomething() error {
    e := &MissingAttrError{missingAttr: "Key"}
    return fmt.Errorf("DoSomething(): %w", e)
}

func main() {
    err := DoSomething()
    expectedErrOne := &MissingAttrError{}
    expectedErrTwo := &AnotherError{}
    expectedErrs := []error{expectedErrOne, expectedErrTwo}

    fmt.Printf("Is err '%v' type '%T'?: %t\n", err, expectedErrOne, errors.As(err, &expectedErrOne))
    fmt.Printf("Is err '%v' type '%T'?: %t\n", err, expectedErrTwo, errors.As(err, &expectedErrTwo))

    for i := range expectedErrs {
        fmt.Printf("Is err '%v' type '%T'?: %t\n", err, expectedErrs[i], errors.As(err, &expectedErrs[i]))

    }
}
```

The output of this is

```
Is err 'DoSomething(): missing attribute: Key' type '*main.MissingAttrError'?: true
Is err 'DoSomething(): missing attribute: Key' type '*main.AnotherError'?: false
Is err 'DoSomething(): missing attribute: Key' type '*fmt.wrapError'?: true
Is err 'DoSomething(): missing attribute: Key' type '*fmt.wrapError'?: true
```

Ideally I'd like the output to be

```
Is err 'DoSomething(): missing attribute: Key' type '*main.MissingAttrError'?: true
Is err 'DoSomething(): missing attribute: Key' type '*main.AnotherError'?: false
Is err 'DoSomething(): missing attribute: Key' type '*main.MissingAttrError'?: true
Is err 'DoSomething(): missing attribute: Key' type '*main.AnotherError'?: false
```

The reasons for having the slice of errors is that I'd like to be able to define a list of expected errors per test case entry. Say I know that providing the function with certain input will take it down a path that should return an error that wraps a specific error.

How can I convert the `*fmt.wrapError` type from the `[]error` slice back into the original type, so I can use it with `error.As`?

I know I can coerce it into a specific type with `.(AnotherError)`, but to make that work when iterating the slice, I'd have to do that for every possible error the function can return, no?)

Comment: In the loop you are using an `*error` instead of `*expectedErrTwo`. The point of `errors.As` is to look for a specific error, but you're not supplying a specific error, you supplying most most generic one. This just replaces your error with a generic `error` that you asked for.

Comment: @JimB, yeah it replaces it with an error of type *fmt.wrapError, which makes it return true pretty much always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trick `errors.As` using this:

```
func main() {
    err := DoSomething()
    m := &MissingAttrError{}
    a := &AnotherError{}
    expected := []any{&m, &a}

    for i := range expected {
        fmt.Printf("Is err '%v' type '%T'?: %t\n", err, expected[i], errors.As(err, expected[i]))
    }
}
```

The printed type is not what you expect, but `errors.As` works as it should.

The reason your example did not work is because what you are passing  to `errors.As` is a `*error`. Thus, the wrapped error value (which is `err`) is directly assigned to the target value. In my example, the value passed to `errors.As` is a `**AnotherError`, and `err` cannot be assigned to `*AnotherError`.